Phoenix + Vite + Bun
I want to use vitejs over phoenix trough bun. The first thing I did was add watcher to config/dev.exs
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  # Binding to loopback ipv4 address prevents access from other machines.
  # Change to `ip: {0, 0, 0, 0}` to allow access from other machines.
  http: [ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, port: 4000],
  check_origin: false,
  code_reloader: true,
  debug_errors: true,
  secret_key_base: "",
  watchers: [
    bun: ~w(run dev)
  ]

and vite.config.js
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "node:url";

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

process.on("SIGINT", () => {
  console.log("Received SIGINT, stopping watcher...");
  process.exit(0); 
});

process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
  console.log("Received SIGTERM, stopping watcher...");
  process.exit(0); 
});

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "~/": fileURLToPath(new URL("./", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 3001,
    cors: true,
    origin: "http://0.0.0.0:4000",
  },
  build: {
    outDir: "../../priv/static",
    emptyOutDir: true,
    manifest: true,
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        main: fileURLToPath(new URL("./assets/main.js", import.meta.url)),
      },
    },
  },
});

and it works, but when phx server is stoped and terminal released, bun is not stoped, and vite still locking port 3001, and when i run again mix phx.server, vite starts on next available port 3001, and so on. Looks like bun does not receive SIGINT | SIGTERM.
So question is - how to stop automatically bun and unlock port 3001.
And one thing more, when i run bun run dev directly in terminal, i have pretty colorized output, it would be nice to have the same output trough mix phx.server command, and usually i run server trough command iex -S mix phx.server, to keep elixir shell input, i would like to keep this two things if it possible.
